# Create Help and Manual for MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a small application that needs to have a professional looking Help/Manual section. The help would consist of:

- HowTos
- FAQ
- References

I am wondering if there is a free (Easy to learn) tool that can help me produce these documents in HTML format? Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help

Comment: One view here... if your web app needs a manual *you are doing it wrong*

Comment: No I am not! this is an internal web application that is designed for admins to manage specific business function, so it needs to have some kind of user manual. If the task wasn't this specific you were right.

Comment: fair enough - just checking ;p

Answer (score 2):

for a new MVC application we are designing right now we plan to use an external help site in a wiki form. There are wiki engines like mediawiki and others, the idea is to have context sensitive help ( different help page opened from different application pages ) and also to allow users to add content like formulas and examples afterwards.

The cool thing is that a wiki track changes and does the versioning for us and for free so help can grow being fully decoupled from our application source code and users can see who has added what if they want.

in our case, it's only an Intranet application so in fact we have no security issues in the internal network.

Comment: This solution wouldn't work for me. My users are executive's assistance, not very techsavvy . Wiki seems to be a little over kill for this. Plus, the help wouldn't really need to be changed unless we change the application in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create more or lesss that has MSDN for instance.

1. It has two columns
2. The firsrt column has list of descriptions
3. The second column is text + images + video + links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Simplest approach is to use static files and resources. Try it.

In ASP .Net MVC you can create special `_LayoutFAQ.cshtml` and apply it to `IFRAME` pages.

The Index FAQ page could look like following

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FAQ";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h5 class="mt-1 text-center text-success mb-0">My mega FAQ</h5>
    <hr class="mt-1" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 overflow-auto pl-0">
            <ul class="">
                <li><a onclick="NavigateIframe('@Url.Content("~/FAQ/Page1")');"  href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="NavigateIframe('@Url.Content("~/FAQ/Page2")');"  href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 border-left">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe style="height:80vh!important;" id="pageContainer" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light  border-top  border-secondary">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="@ViewBag.PreviousUrl" class="nav-link border border-secondary bottomMenuItem" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Back"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Back</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        });
        function NavigateIframe(url) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#pageContainer").prop("src", url);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
}
@section head{
    <style type="text/css">     
    </style>
}
```

But if your FAQ changes often you probably have to replicate backend and frontend  like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio